# Rails routing and how to keep category view DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that has a belongs_to association to categories.

Example:

- Thing

  - belongs_to :category
- Category

  - has_one :thing

Should I make a view file for each category to find the given category, example:

```
views/things/category_name1.html.erb
views/things/category_name2.html.erb
views/things/category_name3.html.erb
views/things/category_name4.html.erb
```

Or is there a more convenient way to do this?

The views are the same for each category except for the category name in the `find` method. I have tried this:

```
<%= Thing.find(:all, :conditions => {:category => 'Name of category'}) %>
```

I want my url to be `/category_name/name_of_thing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem will handle the URL generation that you're looking for.  In your routes, you'll want to have something along the lines of (Rails 3).  You do not want to have a view for each category -- this should be dynamic.

```
resources :categories do
  resources :things
end
```

Comment: That gem is more robust than my hardcore but basic answer (+1)

Comment: How do I create the views dynamic in the controller and where should the category view "template" go?

Comment: Have a look at the Getting Started guide in the "show" resource section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-an-individual-post

Comment: Should I change the params in show action to use friendly url?

Comment: If you're using friendly_id, you do not need to change params.  The gem handles it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No! Don't create redundant views like that.

Put the following code in your `Category` model, and any other model you wish to have descriptive URLs:

```
def to_param
  return "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
end
```

Assuming `name` is an attribute of `Category`, this will create unique URLs containing the category name. If you know that name will definitely be unique, you can replace the return line with just `name.parameterize`.

Comment: Using to_param will work too, but with just name.parameterize you'll also need to update the Category.find(params[:id]) calls in the controller.

Comment: Should I make a category layout? How do I create the views dynamic?

Comment: In the `show` method of your `CategoryController` you need to get the appropriate object and put it in a variable. Since it seems you're a bit unsure about this, I **highly** recommend that you read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), in particular the [section on controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), but you should definitely read the entire guide.

Comment: +1 on reading the guides.  They cover all the basics in depth.  If you run into any issues when running through them though, feel free to post questions.